# Google App engine Deployment Error

Tags: google-app-engine

I just tried to deploy the exact program which is given in the following link

http://blog.abahgat.com/2013/01/07/user-authentication-with-webapp2-on-google-app-engine/

This program works fine in my local and there was no error in log files. But while deployment it rolled back by throwing some server error. Please help me to solve this issue!

```
2015-06-17 11:21:34 Running command: "['C:\\Python27\\python.exe', '-u', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\google_appengine\\appcfg.py', '--oauth2_credential_file=C:\\Users\\Yuvaraj/.appcfg_oauth2_tokens', 'update', 'D:\\Workspace\\userAccount']"
11:21 AM Application: userauthentication-979; version: 1
11:21 AM Host: appengine.google.com
11:21 AM 
Starting update of app: userauthentication-979, version: 1
11:21 AM Getting current resource limits.
11:21 AM Scanning files on local disk.
11:21 AM Cloning 17 application files.
11:21 AM Compilation starting.
2015-06-17 11:22:52,510 WARNING util.py:126 new_request() takes at most 1 positional argument (6 given) 
2015-06-17 11:23:54,213 WARNING util.py:126 new_request() takes at most 1 positional argument (6 given) 
2015-06-17 11:23:54,213 WARNING util.py:126 new_request() takes at most 1 positional argument (6 given) 
11:24 AM Error 500: --- begin server output ---

<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>500 Server Error</title>
</head>
<body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff>
<h1>Error: Server Error</h1>
<h2>The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.<p>Please try again in 30 seconds.</h2>
<h2></h2>
</body></html>
--- end server output ---

You can close this window now.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When stuff like this happens, the first/best place to look is [status.cloud.google.com](http://status.cloud.google.com)

This was a known issue and is fixed: https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/appengine/15019

> The issue with application deployment was resolved as of Wednesday,
>   2015-06-17 00:00. Again we do apologize for the inconvenience and
>   thank you for your patience and continued support. Please rest assured
>   that system reliability is a top priority at Google, and we are making
>   continuous improvements to make our systems better. We will provide a
>   more detailed analysis of this incident once we have completed our
>   internal investigation.